# What is the lightest linux os for older computer

Tags: custom-distributions, distro-recommendation

I have a computer that has 2 gb ram and not very good other features.I want to run `Android Developer Studio` on this computer and I want to use linux distribution.Which linux distribution can I use ?

**EDIT**
If I should be more clear,
Is LXLE or Lubuntu is good for me or not ?

Comment: Tinycore or similar

Comment: Lubuntu is similar to Windows XP in how lightweight it is and also the desktop environment theming is minimalistic like XP. [Lubuntu 14.04 Screenshot Tour](http://www.linuxscreenshots.org/?release=Lubuntu%2014.04)

Comment: Lubuntu should work. And its desktop environment is called LXDE.